# как сравнивать версии ПО с помощью Python?

Tags: python, ооп, version

Нужно написать класс Version. чтобы создавать экземпляры и потом иметь возможность сравнивать их между собой как версии.
Пример:

```
Version('1.1.3') < Version('2.2.3')
# True

Version('1.3.0') > Version('0.3.0')
# True
```

Насколько я понимаю, нужно переопределить методы **le** и т.п. но не совсем понимаю как это сделать. Провбовал импортировать from distutils.version import Version, LooseVersion, StrictVersion. но мне нужно именно написать свой класс

Comment: Не переопределить, а определить методы сравнения в своём классе `Version`, который вы должны написать. С чем именно у вас проблема - вы не умеете описывать методы или вы не можете придумать как сравнить версии по сути?

Comment: @CrazyElf Из за того, что я не понимаю, как обращаться с версиями, не могу определить и эти методы. Их я вроде как определять умею. писал для сравненения времени друг с другом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Берем класс, в котором всё есть и делаем из него свой:

```
class Version(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, text):
        return super().__new__(cls, tuple(int(x) for x in text.split('.')))
```

`__new__` потому как tuple инициализируется до `__init__`

```
>>> Version('1.1.3') < Version('2.2.3')
True
>>> Version('1.3.0') > Version('0.3.0')
True
```

Для наглядности методов сравнения реализуются функции

```
class Version:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.version = tuple(int(x) for x in text.split('.'))
        
    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.version <= other.version
        
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.version >= other.version
        
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.version < other.version
        
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.version > other.version
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.version == other.version

    def __str__(self):
        return '.'.join(self.version)
```

Но если версии разной длинны нужно вводить функцию сравнения:

```
import itertools

class Version:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.version = tuple(int(x) for x in text.split('.'))
        
    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.__cmp(other.version) <= 0
        
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.__cmp(other.version) >= 0
        
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.__cmp(other.version) < 0
        
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.__cmp(other.version) > 0
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__cmp(other.version) == 0
        
    def __cmp(self, b):
        a = self.version
        for x,y in itertools.zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0):
            if x != y:
                return x - y
        return 0
```

Тогда

```
>>> Version('1.1') == Version('1.1.0')
True
```

Comment: Супер! спасибо большое! Все как работает!

Answer (score 0):

В итоге пришел к этому. Просто нашел еще ,что версии могут содержать буквы и слова типо alpha и т.п.

```
class Version:
def __init__(self, version):
    """
    The versions are reduced to a format of five numeric values separated by a dot.
    1.2.0.0.0
    The class returns a tuple.

    :param version: str
    :return tuple: ('*','*','*','*','*')
    """
    lst = version.split('.')
    version_lst = []

    for ind in lst:

        verbal_version = re.findall('[a-z]{1,5}', ind)

        if verbal_version != []:
            try:
                temp_val = verbal_version[0]
                if temp_val == 'a' or temp_val == 'alpha':
                    r = 0
                elif temp_val == 'b' or temp_val == 'beta':
                    r = 1
                elif temp_val == 'rc':
                    r = 2
                elif temp_val == 'r':
                    r = 3
                else:
                    raise ValueError
            except ValueError:
                print('Undefined version')
                break

            digital_version = re.findall('\d{1,5}', ind)
            if digital_version != []:
                version_lst.append(digital_version[0])

            version_lst.append(r)

        else:
            version_lst.append(ind)

    while len(version_lst) < 5:
        version_lst.append('0')
```